# jquery validation field is not clearing error after blur or submit

Tags: jquery, validation

I've fixed this issue before (inadvertently) and I'm coming across this again.  Hopefully someone will be able to help me.

I have a form using jquery's validation plugin (bassisstance.de).

The form validation is working fine except for one issue.

When qualifying a field after it's been classed as "error" the field class doesn't clear.  It stays red.  Submitting the form (with other errors) or blurring from the field that was just fixed, stays red.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I figured it out! some simple HTML changes needed. Don't do this:  REVERSE IT!  Everything worked just fine after that. Stumbled on that on a whim.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but this answer doesn't really explain anything, and therefore isn't very useful to anyone.